# AWS lambda task timeout after 3 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i am trying to execute my lambda function in AWS, its giving me timeout error even though my code is correct. any   help is appreciated.

Comment: Increase the timeout, 3s is the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try to increase timeout to desired time in AWS lambda configuration setting.

Comment: @shekarsb If the answer helped, a good practice is to  [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) it.